# Connect to wifi not possible

Tags: networking, internet, 19.04

I have previously had a problem with NetworkManager that was solved, however, there is an error in wlan0 not being found and the Raise network interface failing to start.
I have tried in the past to make a USB of pau05 work, which I later found it to be dead. Which before I found out, I made a vim file that messed up the network manager, I then henceforth deleted the vim text file I created after failing to fix the adapter, which was seemingly the solution to making network manager work again, this code is what I used to make the text file

```
sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi.scan-rand-mac-address.conf > /dev/null <<EOF
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
EOF
sudo service network-manager restart
```

However, these other areas have not worked and so I cannot connect. If there is any other information I need to provide, please tell me.

### I have tried previous solutions, yet they did not work.

### Any help is appreciated.

Logs of Raise network interface not working
[image: Raise network interface not working]
Terminal line of it  seemingly crashing
[image: Systemctl status of networking.service]
wlan0 log of it not being found
[image: wlan0 not being found]

Comment: In general, when you can copy-and-paste the contents of a terminal session (such as your #2 and #3 picture above) and provides us with the _test_ of those sessions or logs, we infinitely prefer that to screenshots or pictures.  Just paste what you got off the screen on log into your question. Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, which previous solutions did you try? The web links would be most helpful, as would the results seen on screen when you tried them.  Please click [edit] and add what you tried and the result into the question. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

service have to be restarted`

**Issue One: Device not detected**

```
sudo lsusb
sudo lspci
```

[image]

`lshw -C network`

Output similar as this:

> ```
> *-network
> description: Wireless interface
>
> product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
>
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> ```

**Issue Two: Driver module missing**

```
sudo lsmod
sudo modprobe modulename
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
sudo nano /etc/modules
man lsusb
man lspci
```

**Issue Three: DNS**

```
nmcli device show wlan1 | grep IP4.DNS
ip address
ping 8.8.8.8
```

As a final step, either restart your machine or restart the Network Manager from the Terminal:

`sudo service network-manager restart`